# Nginx SSL cant connect to site

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I just bought a SSL certicate for my website and tried to get it working with my nginx install, but uppon connection the browser refuses the connection with the website. Here is the relevant part of the Vhost:

```
     server {
          listen 80;
          listen [::]:80;
           server_name mysite.be www.mysite.be;
           return 301 https://mysite.be$request_uri;
        }

    server {

       listen 443 ssl spdy;
        listen [::]:443 ssl spdy;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.be/www.mysite.be.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.be/mysite.be.key;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;   # don.t use SSLv3 because of the POODLE attack

       # Enable OCSP Stapling, point to certificate chain
       ssl_stapling on;
       ssl_stapling_verify on;
          # Tell the browser we do SPDY
         # add_header        Alternate-Protocol  443:npn-spdy/2;


            server_name mysite  *.mysite.be;

[.....]
```

The config you see abov

The nginx.conf part:

```
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 10s;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:32m;
ssl_buffer_size 8k;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
```

I don't know what I did wrong, I followed many tutorials to get to this point and then it just doesn't work.

Comment: You have things duplicated, e.g. ssl_stapling and ssl_ciphers. Does your nginx support ssl_stapling?  The logs *must* say something, show that in your question.

Comment: You mention following many tutorials but not what you have specifically done, what did not work, and potentially why it did not work. Can you please include these in your question?

Comment: I recommend you to look into to the error log for nginx first. Maybe it shows you already what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The first server configuration is a redirect to HTTPS (second configuration).

In the second server configuration SPDY module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the `--with-http_spdy_module` configuration parameter.
Note that in order to accept both HTTPS and SPDY connections simultaneously on the same port, OpenSSL library used should support “Next Protocol Negotiation” TLS extension, available since OpenSSL version 1.0.1 ([reference here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_spdy_module.html)).

I would write the second server configuration in this way (PoC):

```
server {
  listen       443;
  server_name  .mysite.be;

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.be/www.mysite.be.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.be/mysite.be.key;

  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  root [YOUR_ROOT_DIR]
  ...
}
```

In the `nginx.conf` I would omit all the things regarding SSL and keep it by default.

Comment: Will give it a try when i have time, thx :)